# Can you update the row returned in a then() callback after a find()?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I need to find the users row in my database via the users username, then use that username to find it's friend request in the requests table, then:

- Update the request to prevent duplicate requests
- Add the notification message to the user's notifications array
- Emit to the user via the socket ID in it's row

Can you update a mongo row in then()?

I tried this in my callback:

```
requester.update({ $push: { 'notifications': {'msg': msg, 'type': type} } });
```

This is it's context:

```
      User.find({'username': requester}).exec()
      .then(requester => {
          Request.findOneAndUpdate({'requester': requester[0]._id, 'requestee': requestee.user._id}, {'status': 1}).then(function(){
              const msg = requestee.user.username + ' accepted your friend request ',
                    type = 1;
              requester.update({ $push: { 'notifications': {'msg': msg, 'type': type} } });
              app.io.to(requester[0].socket).emit({'msg': msg, 'type': type});
          });
      })
      .catch(err => { 
         console.log(err);
      });
```

I currently get: **TypeError: requester.update is not a function**

Answer (score 0):

You can update mongodb result in then. If you using `$push` you should call the model not the result of the model.

```
 User.update({ _id: 1 }, { $push: { 'notifications': {'msg': msg, 'type': type} } });
```

That clearly doesn't work because `requester` are just JavaScript object from your `User.find()`

Side note : if you just want to find one user use `findOne` instead `find`. `find` will return array, and `findOne` will return object

Comment: User object will automatically be the one from the find? I'll do that, but do you have any more info on this, and how it works?

Thanks!

Comment: I just answer your question on *Can you update a mongo row in then()?* and point your fault on *TypeError: requester.update is not a function*. 

find always returning an array in mongoose you can look at the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find) so if you only looking for one user in your database you could use `findOne()` it will return object. so you dont have to use `result[0].name` only `result.name`

Comment: Your solution isn't working, and I'm not getting an error. I get a console log before and after the User.update(), but nothing is pushed on the array

Comment: As I said above, I only answering your question on that topic. 

When using `$push ` you should pass the identifier , you can use `_id` or whatever you want  `User.update({ _id: 1 }, { $push: { 'notifications': {'msg': msg, 'type': type} } });` I hope you read the [manual first](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) Ill edit my answer